# Define string conversion settings for JProperty.Value(Set)

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I have this extension function:

```
<Extension> Sub SetPropertiesValue(jsontoken As JToken, 
                                   propertypath As String, 
                                   newvalue As Object)
    Dim jsonproperties = jsontoken.SelectTokens(propertypath).OfType(Of JValue).Select(Function(jv) jv.Parent).OfType(Of JProperty)
    For Each jp In jsonproperties
        jp.Value = newvalue
    Next
End Sub
```

When I pass as `newvalue` a string with non-ASCII characters, like "açúcar", it sets property as `"propertyname" : "açúcar"`.

How do I tell JSON.NET to escape non-ASCII characters so the resullt of the operation be `"propertyname" : "a\u00e7\u00facar"`?

Comment: While this was certainly anticipated in JSON and Json.NET, are you sure you are solving a problem that needs to be solved and solving it in the right place? JSON files and streams are required to use a Unicode encoding, making such escaping unnecessary. In fact, the story for VB source files is somewhat similar. VB source files _can_ be encoded in a non-Unicode encoding with escapes if needed but like JSON the content is ultimately Unicode. (JSON and VB are typically encoded with UTF-8, one of the Unicode encodings.) So what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Well, as for my reason, I wrote a program to send bulky data to an intranet application by circumventing its lame interface and sending json postdata directly to the server via http request, and it works. But it does it by find-and-replace on template json strings, and I wanted to do this more consistently using JToken. Since all communications I examined did escape all non-ascii characters, I would like to do no differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Json.NET, escaping of strings doesn't occur when creating a [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) hierarchy.  It occurs only during the final conversion to a *JSON string* by setting [`JsonWriter.StringEscapeHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_StringEscapeHandling.htm).  This is because string escaping is an artifact of the *string representation* of JSON.  Since a `JToken` hierarchy represents *already tokenized and parsed* JSON, escaping of control characters inside string literals is no longer required.

Once you have your `JToken` root object, you can control string escaping during final output by setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_StringEscapeHandling.htm) then serializing your object:

```
    Dim settings = New JsonSerializerSettings With { _
        .StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii _
    }
    Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsontoken, Formatting.Indented, settings)
```

Or if you prefer working with lower-level utilities you can construct your own [`JsonTextWriter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm) with the appropriate setting as follows:

```
    Dim sb = new StringBuilder()
    Using textWriter as new StringWriter(sb)
        Using jsonWriter as new JsonTextWriter(textWriter) With { .StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii, .Formatting = Formatting.Indented }
            jsontoken.WriteTo(jsonWriter)
        End Using
    End Using
    Dim json = sb.ToString()
```

The possible values for `StringEscapeHandling` are shown [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_StringEscapeHandling.htm):

```
Default         0   Only control characters (e.g. newline) are escaped.
EscapeNonAscii  1   All non-ASCII and control characters (e.g. newline) are escaped.
EscapeHtml      2   HTML (<, >, &, ', ") and control characters (e.g. newline) are escaped.
```

Example [VB.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/77p5LS).